# TeamCity - Specifying the previous build version as build step parameter

Tags: teamcity-9.0

I have a project in TeamCity where one of the build steps calls an exe with parameters consisting of currentReleaseId/PreviousReleaseID.

Current release is simple enough because I can just use %build.counter% built into TC. Does anyone know how can I get the %build.counter% - 1 id to pass as the second param?

Current setup:

TeamCity Build Step
Run: Executable with parameters

Command executable:
\CIS\E$\PerformanceTracker\ConsoleApp\PerformanceTracker.ConsoleApp.exe

Command parameters: %build.counter% r1.0.45

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can define an environment variable for your build configruation (i.e. env.RELEASE_VERSION)

[image: Define environment variable]

Then click `edit` and define the parameter specificaiton. Here you define how to select/enter the value for the environment variable

[image: Edit parameter specification]

After defining the variable it could be referenced in the build configuration in the same manner as `%build.counter%` (i.e. `%env.RELEASE_VERSION%`). If you then start the build you will be prompted to enter the value for the release version parameter

Comment: Thanks for your response, sorry for the slow reply.