# How to get the version number of the last successful build?

Tags: teamcity, continuous-deployment

**Background**

I have a third-party web service with methods for installing and uninstalling an artifact. Both when installing and uninstalling, you specify an artifact named package-%maven.project.version%.zip. Before installing a new package, I need to uninstall the previously installed package.

**Solutions**

I found this [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31127030/teamcity-specifying-the-previous-build-version-as-build-step-parameter), but as this is the final step to achieve continuous deployment, I need something automated and not a prompt.

Another solution that can be automated by a build step is to make use of the TeamCity REST API:

1. Call http://localhost/httpAuth/app/rest/builds/?locator=buildType:Development,count:1,status:SUCCESS
2. Use build id in response from step 1 to call http://localhost/httpAuth/app/rest/builds/id:[build-id]/resulting-properties
3. Retrieve value from the following node in the response from step 2, `<property name="maven.project.version" value="1.2.3"/>`.

**Question**

Is there a simpler way than using the TeamCity REST API?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So, I decided on using the TeamCity REST API from a PowerShell build step to retrieve `%maven.project.version%` from the last successful build:

```
$client = New-Object System.Net.WebClient
$client.Credentials = New-Object System.Net.NetworkCredential $username, $password

$latestBuildUrl = "http://localhost/httpAuth/app/rest/builds/?locator=buildType:Development,count:1,status:SUCCESS"
[xml]$latestBuild = $client.DownloadString($latestBuildUrl)
$latestBuildId = $latestBuild.builds.build.id

$propertiesUrl = "http://localhost/httpAuth/app/rest/builds/id:$latestBuildId/resulting-properties"
[xml]$properties = $client.DownloadString($propertiesUrl)
$mavenProjectVersion = $properties.SelectSingleNode("//property[@name='maven.project.version']").value
```

Answer (score 1):

I think your approach is sound.

Another approach would be:

1. your build prints `%maven.project.version%` into a file
2. your build config publishes the file as an artifact
3. you download something like `/repository/download/BUILD_TYPE_EXT_ID/.lastSuccessful/ARTIFACT_PATH` (read more [here](https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD9/Patterns+For+Accessing+Build+Artifacts))

I guess it's a little easier to implement but a bit more messy (extra steps/files = clutter).

Answer (score 1):

**This will work on TeamCity Enterprise 2018.1.1:**
`http://<teamcity_hostname>/httpAuth/app/rest/buildTypes/<your_build_type>/builds/status:success/number`

To get your available build types and other build attributes use:
`http://<teamcity_hostname>/httpAuth/app/rest/builds`