# powershell script to get the latest build number from Teamcity buildJob

Tags: powershell, teamcity, powershell-3.0

Please help me to get the latest build number from Teamcity build Job from the Build URL.
Thanks In advance

Comment: Try this [stackoverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54076683/6792588) (duplicate)

Answer (score 0):

```
PS /> [xml] $xml = curl -u login:password teamcity:8111/httpAuth/app/rest/buildTypes/id:<your Buld id>/builds/running:false
PS /> $xml.build.number
7.123.12
```

where  is Build configuration ID